# showing numbers on textview

Tags: android

What i m trying to do is, just showing numbers from 1 to 100 in a textview, randomly, and keep on changing until the view is active.

But i am not able to continuously change random number when view is active.

it is just like a timer  showing decrement from 10 to 0, but the only difference is i need to show random numbers in between 0 to 100.

How can show this on my view
this is how i am trying to do something..may be a better approch will help me out

```
if (hasFocus) {
   try {  
      //Give the currentTimeMillis some time for the seed  
      Thread.sleep(2);  
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {  
      ex.printStackTrace();  
   }  
   Random randomizer = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());  
   // abcdef  = randomizer.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
   return randomizer.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;  
} else { }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with until the view is active? I am not sure how you are realizing this in your code, but could it be the case that you are actually writing the numbers into your view in a loop? In that case you are probably updating the UI to often which will lead to a crash or unwanted behavior. I'd suggest to put a delay between two different numbers. 
Maybe I misunderstood your question though. Some code showing what you are trying to do might be helpful.

Comment: i edited my question, u can look at ma code.
I just wanted to randomize number and keep showing, with refershing or something like dat, my view should show  random no cotiniously.
regards

Comment: Well if you just want to write random numbers into a TextView, I would create a Thread with an endless loop. Just use (int)(Math.Random()*100) to get the number and store it in some global variable. Then use a Handler to tell the Activity there is a new number and let the Handler update the TextView. After you did that just sleep the thread for like 200ms. You will need a loop and loops in your main activity are something bad to do. A Thread will be needed. You can check this tutorial on how to use a handler: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog

Comment: u took me wrong.
i dont want that,
i just need to show some random numbers in b/w 1 to 100, on a textview, which should keep on changing automatically.
thats all..m i clear dude?

Comment: Well unless I still don't get you, that is exactly what I told you. Here is the code to do it. http://pastebin.com/cc2PLA10 Just paste it in a project and get an main.xml with a TextView in it under the id TextView01.  
If this doesn't explain it then well I can't help you.